# Why we can not fetch more than one value at a time in PL SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

Why we can not fetch more than one value at a time in PL SQL? Why cursor is required?

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. There are several ways to fetch data in PL/SQL. And of course you can fetch several values at a time. Your question as is, makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing what you are asking is how to fetch many rows at a time (but you could do with asking the question with a bit more detail). This can be accomplished by bulk collect into a collection. Here is an example:

```
PROCEDURE process_all_rows
IS
   TYPE employees_aat 
   IS TABLE OF employees%ROWTYPE
      INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
   l_employees employees_aat;
BEGIN
   SELECT *
   BULK COLLECT INTO l_employees
      FROM employees;

   FOR indx IN 1 .. l_employees.COUNT 
   LOOP
       analyze_compensation 
      (l_employees(indx));
   END LOOP;
END process_all_rows;
```

From this article http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Comment: Yes. I was asking about how to fetch many rows at a time. I should have described it clearly. can we extract the all rows of a table using for loop and without cursor.

Comment: As described above you can fetch all into a collection - bulk collect. I wouldn't recommend this if you are likely to have a large number of rows though. You can find a description here (more rows at a time, faster but more memory used) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2008/08-mar/o28plsql-095155.html

Answer (score 0):

> Why we can not fetch more than one value at a time in PL SQL?

Yes, you can.

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> DECLARE
  2  v_empno NUMBER;
  3  v_sal NUMBER;
  4  BEGIN
  5  SELECT empno, sal into v_empno, v_sal FROM emp WHERE ename='SCOTT';
  6  dbms_output.put_line('1st value Empno is = '||v_empno||' , 2nd value sal is = '||v_Sal);
  7  END;
  8  /
1st value Empno is = 7788 , 2nd value sal is = 3000

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

> Why cursor is required?

That is too broad question to answer unless you narrow down to a specifics. Also, it seems like you are confusing between **values** and **rows**. In the above example, in the PL/SQL block it returned two values using **INTO** clause, however, it is a single row.